# Mapbox sdk 7 show image on infowindow

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using mapbox android sdk 7 trying to show some images on infowindow with no luck.
The doc says infowindow is deprecated and that I should use annotation plugin, but I can't find an example in this annotation plugin that shows an infowindow when marker is clicked
Please, if someone knows something about it I'll appreciate it

Comment: See advice at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/901

A non-plugin implementation to try:

InfoWindow SymbolLayer: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity.java

Comment: Instead of adjusting TextViews in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity.java#L344-L367, try setting the image to an ImageView that you've added to `R.layout.symbol_layer_info_window_layout_callout`.